# SQLite Distinct With 2 Unique Column

Tags: sqlite, case, sql-order-by, distinct, window-functions

I'm using SQLite. I want to get every data rows in 2 columns are unique.

This example data in `order_transaction` table:

| date_transaction | customer |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-11 | Dio |
| 2022-05-11 | Dio |
| 2022-05-11 | Jotaro |

When I use the `distinct` query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_transaction, customer FROM order_transaction;
```

The output is:

| date_transaction | customer |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-11 | Dio |
| 2022-05-11 | Jotaro |

Ok so I get `customer` unique row, but how can I get the `date_transaction` unique row like this?

| date_transaction | customer |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-11 | Dio |
|  | Jotaro |

What query can get that output?

I'm new in SQLite. Sorry :)

Comment: Do this in your presentation code, not the query. Use `ORDER BY date_transaction, customer`, and then the loop that prints the result should check if the current date is the same as the previous date, and leave it blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `CASE` expression and `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.date_transaction ORDER BY t.customer) = 1 THEN t.date_transaction END date_transaction, 
       t.customer
FROM order_transaction t
GROUP BY t.date_transaction, t.customer
ORDER BY t.date_transaction, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.date_transaction ORDER BY t.customer);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=21dff3d73aeb8048051f25753534f8c9).